# Delete User If Email Never Activated

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.6

Is there a way, or a component/plugin to automate the process of deleting users who register on my site, but never activate their email?

So after 30 days, their account automatically is deleted.

I have been searching for this for a while.

Thanks,
Melvins138

Answer (score 2):

Can't guarantee the quality of any third party extensions, but there seems to be one here:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/juserprune/

If you have the coding knowledge to write your own plugin, then the information you need is in the `__users` table of your database.

The date a user registered will be in `registerDate` field and if they have never activated their account, the `activation` field will be populated and the `lastvisitdate` will be `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  From this you could write a database query to generate a list of users to delete.

Ideally you should delete them using JUser's delete function, so that it caputures any related data, though viewing that function at libraries\joomla\table\user.php shows you what needs to be done to clean up the database.

I'd probably then pop the script in a plugin that is fired `onUserBeforeSave`, so that it tidies itself whenever someone creates or updates an account (this event seems the most appropriate), though you could use Cron if it needs to be more regular than that.

(I assume you know, but if you want to do it manually, it is possible to use the filters at the top of the user manager to find these users.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to both the answers. I looked into both, and found a paid component that will do several features I need.

Thanks for the help.

The component is called [RegReminder](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/regreminder).

Answer (score 1):

[Admin Tools Professional](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/admin-tools-professional) includes the "System - Admin Tools" plugin which has an option to delete inactive users after a specified number of days. The plugin also includes options for session, cache and temp file cleanup.

This extension is not free but includes a wealth of other tools which you can read about in the link. If all you need to do is clean up inactive users, then the free extension suggested by Richard may be the best option.